# Should jitdebugging be disabled in production releases?

Tags: c#, debugging, jit, production

As the title says, should Just-In-Time debugging be disabled in production releases?

Thank you all.

Comment: Rather small odds that it works at all, you'd have to install Visual Studio on the production machine so vsjitdebugger.exe is copied and registered.  Well, don't do that, nothing to "disable" either.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I realize it is a weird question but, well, I couldn't figure out the answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Just-In-Time debugging debugging is enabled, a dialog box will appear when an unhandled exception occurs in a program running outside Visual Studio. This dialog box gives you an opportunity to debug the program.

So is there someone who can deal with such dialog boxes when they appear? If yes, then it's OK to keep Just-In-Time debugging debugging enabled in the production computer. Otherwise, this may be undesirable for unattended operation and therefore you should disable it.